# Tiny int of MySQL to Integer in Java

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have an `tiny int` column in MySQL. I want to convert it into int type of java.

So if I mention the column in my hibernate entity as

```
@Column(name="Columname")
private int something;
```

Will it cause an error as tiny int needs boolean type or will it get cast into int?

This code will be changed in production Db hence I cannot check it to see if it breaks.

Comment: Test it on your own, local database. If it works fine, then only think about applying the change to production. You won't ask us for every little thing, won't you?

Comment: tiny int in MySQL is what boolean is in Java.

Comment: It works on local. I just hope there aren't any use cases I am missing . Thanks though.

Comment: Should be no problem, explicitly mentioned int - BIT(1) compatibility: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/ndbapi/en/mccj-using-clusterj-mappings.html

Comment: Can you please write in answer section so that I canmark it as correct answer?:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JDBC driver maps databse type to java. So in case of mysql `TINYINT` will be converted to `java.lang.Boolean` or `java.lang.Integer`.

Refer this link which explains :  [Java, JDBC and MySQL Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html)

Answer (score 4):

Go for the datatype **Byte**. it worked for me!